# Why is this question being voted to be closed?

Tags: discussion

I think my question is well-framed, within subject, and systemic. Maybe it's not possible to do what I want to do, but I think the question is valid.

So, why is it being voted to be closed?

[How to Retain File Names that are being mangled when I Move/ Cut Files from Recycle Bin to a selected folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1218485/how-to-retain-file-names-that-are-being-mangled-when-i-move-cut-files-from-recy)

Comment: Your question might be on-topic and valid, but it is difficult to tell what exactly your problem really is and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Mokubai - Updated Question, Found solution elsewhere, Posted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The three votes so far say "unclear what you're asking". Part of that may be because the majority of your sentences do not follow the subject/predicate structure of English. When you aren't writing in English, it's quite reasonable for people to close the question as "unclear what you're asking".

Spend a little more time making sure your question makes sense. For instance:

> Retain File Names without name mangling when Move/ Cut select Files from Recycle Bin to a selected location

You should start your sentences with *who* or *what* is doing, or trying to do, the "retaining". For example:

> **I'm trying to retain** file names without name mangling when **I** Cut (Move) select**ed** files from Recycle Bin to a selected location.

Then,

> Move/ Cut select Files from Recycle Bin to a selected location retaining File Names without name mangling?

This is essentially repeating the same thing as before. If I were to re-word this to be written in English, I'd say:

> **How can I** Move or Cut selected files from Recycle Bin to a selected location retaining **original** file names without name mangling?

But this is the same thing as the prior sentence, just re-worded into the form of a question. You can pick the one you like better and remove the other.

Next:

> "Windows Behavior" when cutting/ pasting or drag-dropping the files to some location/ folder, all the names are mangled.

I'd reword as:

> The behavior I'm seeing is that when I cut/paste or drag and drop the files from Recycle Bin to some other location, Windows 8.1 mangles all the names. For example, `$REA9O58.xxx` (my original file name does not look anything like that).

The only options Recycle Bin appears to give in the UI are:

- **Restore:** Puts files back in their original folder, and with the proper name. Unfortunately, this can lead to overwriting existing files, which I don't want.

or

- **Cut:** when pasted or Drag & Dropped to new location, the original name is mangled as shown above.

Thus, my question: How can I restore a file from Recycle Bin to any arbitrary folder (different from the original folder) without Windows changing the name of the file?

---

If you wrote your question like this, I don't think the existing close votes would be valid, and we could petition a mod to reopen it (or vote to reopen it and let it process through the queue) if it gets closed.